# In TypeScript, can you define a function type where each argument can be one of multiple types, without using a rest parameter when implementing it?

Tags: typescript

If I have a function type that enforces that each argument must be a number, then I can use it to define a function with each individual argument specified, as below:

```ts
type NumberFunction = (...args: number[]) => void;

const numberFunction: NumberFunction = (arg1: number, arg2: number) => console.log(arg1, arg2);
```

If I want more than 1 argument type to be allowed, I can create the following type:

```ts
type StringOrNumberFunction = (...args: (string | number)[]) => void;
```

But then I can't specify each argument individually when using the type:

```ts
const stringOrNumberFunctionA: StringOrNumberFunction = 
    (...args: (string | number)[]) => console.log(args); // This is allowed

const stringOrNumberFunctionB: StringOrNumberFunction = 
    (arg1: string, arg2: number) => console.log(arg1, arg2); // This is NOT allowed
```

Is there a way of defining a function type that satisfies all of the below criteria?

- Allows any number of arguments
- Enforces that each argument must be 1 of several given types
- Does not require the function type to be implemented with rest parameter syntax (i.e I can define each argument individually)

For context, I am trying to create a method decorator that can only be used when the method in question has arguments that are either strings or numbers. Ideally I want it to complain at compile time rather than at runtime when the decorator is used on a method that has any arguments other than strings or numbers.

Comment: This type doesn't seem very useful. If there was *some magical way* to make a type like this, there's already two problems. 1) You can't call a function with that type, safely. Unless you cast everything to `never`. 2) You can't assign that type to itself. Also, I don't think this is possible (again, even if it was, we'd have the two problems I stated before).

Comment: "_Allows any number of arguments_" and "_Does not require the function type to be implemented with rest parameter syntax_" seem to be incompatible. Are you sure you know exactly what you want? Can you write up a sample of what you are thinking of?

Comment: That is to say, the caller is given a guarantee that they can pass any number of arguments of either string or number (their choice), yet your function `stringOrNumberFunctionB` has 2 required arguments: a string and a number. The caller may call it with fewer or different types, which will cause an error.

Comment: Not sure, but looks like a generic function type with `Params` type parameter is the answer. As in: `type StringOrNumberFunction<Params extends (string | number)[]> = (…args: Params) => void` and then `const fn1: StringOrNumberFunction<[foo: number]> = (foo) => …` and `const fn2: StringOrNumberFunction<[bar: number, baz: string]> = (bar, baz) => …`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Yep this works, and also does satisfy my use case in that it will allow me to create a method decorator that can't be used on any methods I don't want it to be used on. It's a little bothersome that it means you have to specify the arguments twice, but looks like this is really the only answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JDB This is really only so that I can enforce how a method decorator is used. I.E I want the decorator to be able to be used on any method with n arguments where all the arguments are of type string or number, and I want it to complain at compile time if someone tries to use the decorator on a method that doesn't satisfy this condition. If there's another way to approach this problem I'm all ears :)

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Actually ignore my previous comment to you, your solution doesn't require me to specify the arguments twice the way that I'm using it with the decorator, so that's brilliant. This is the answer for sure :)

Comment: Sorry Chris... somehow I completely missed your last paragraph. I'll update me answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explaining the Example Code

Looking just at the example code, here's why the definition is throwing errors:

```js
type StringOrNumberFunction = (...args: (string | number)[]) => void;
```

This type is a contract between an implementation (a specific function) and a caller. The caller might not know specifically which function is being called, but the promise is that I, the caller, can pass as many or as few arguments as I want and that they can be either strings or numbers: my choice.

This function does not satisfy the contract:

```js
// Type '(arg1: string, arg2: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'StringOrNumberFunction'.
const stringOrNumberFunctionB: StringOrNumberFunction = 
    (arg1: string, arg2: number) => console.log(arg1, arg2);
```

This function requires two arguments and they must be specifically a string and then a number. The caller might pass no arguments or two numbers, but that would violate the interface for this function.

You can modify the function to still work with the contract:

```js
const stringOrNumberFunctionC: StringOrNumberFunction = 
    (arg1?: string|number, arg2?: string|number) => console.log(arg1, arg2);
```

This makes the arguments optional and either a string or a number. It satisfies the contract that you created with `StringOrNumberFunction`. The caller can pass two numbers or zero arguments, for example, without violating the interface for your function. It's up to your function to check whether any arguments were passed and if they are a number or string.

#### Building a Well-Typed Decorator:

Jumping off from the [TypeScript 5.0 Well-Typed Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#writing-well-typed-decorators) example, you can accomplish your goal with generics:

```js
function loggedMethod<This, Args extends (string|number)[], Return>(
    target: (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return>
) {
    function replacementMethod(this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
        console.log(...args)
        return target.call(this, ...args);
    }
    return replacementMethod;
}
```

Here's the result:

```js
class Foo {
    // Valid
    @loggedMethod
    validFun(arg1: string, arg2: number) {}

    // Invalid
    // Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
    // Argument of type '(arg1: string, arg2: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Foo, ...args: (string | number)[]) => void'.
    @loggedMethod
    invalidFun(arg1: string, arg2: boolean) {}
}
```

[Link to the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgczQUwCYFlNQAWc2APACqEwDOANIgIIBOa1imAHlJmNmwBTUoTGGDQAfMCAC2AI0xMAlAG0AuvQBKBEEzAA+fgChEJxFACGLAgC5E-IjVuUa9AHTvLrW81aLEAXj1ELSgdMFpjUwgEbi5bAGFkc2pqfCISABFMaKZzKDgmeJjOKAoqOjsHaidytw8WasYGv0Dg7V09Qz8Ab0iTUEhYBEQmTAAHJIhMaR4oNOJse3Kal0R3V09Gn2pFWxCwxF7TY8RosGo4ZExXVDR+dc3FPpPR0N0zTwJXCHNkZCXVg9mgBuZ4AX2erwOowm5imMzAcwIC1BEMMECSKUQADE4HBDs8APSExAANV+MGwzwAArcsHhkSRngA3CnYbHgfieACMtiEIjE9E8ACZbFI5AoemjjsTEABJMCs5CUokkgCqYHMsiuZnxowuyGZmEQ1BgaE1b2NcGAiBm6WwiGw2QKeQKiAA7oQeKdflcHclEOYkJwxvrTQhXKqmmgZLNENazABPMbGgDkXJYvJNwlEaCFLFFiFkeKuQZaQWZcEpqcQNEQYDgUEDKTNmu1xvyiDGlnMdoU8ZtUGTaYBjVxcDqGwatkEObEiHE9Zk8iUanLiEr1cjx1p6Hp8yZx1ESspHLAGbQWf5ufzaELxcumDLhwhYKAA)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, what you want is a type for a function, whose parameters have some custom constraint. This can be achieved easily with generic types or [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
type StringOrNumberFunction<
  Inputs extends (string | number)[],
  Output = void,
> = (...args: Inputs) => Output;

const fn1: StringOrNumberFunction<[foo: number]> = (foo) => {};

const fn2: StringOrNumberFunction<[bar: number, baz: string]> = (bar, baz) => {};

// nope
const fn3: StringOrNumberFunction<[qux: boolean]> = (qux) => {};
```

… where `StringOrNumberFunction` is a generic.

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WzkbRw)*.

Generics can be thought of as types with parameters, which provide additional customization, and often allow doing things that are impossible otherwise. The most common example of a generic type would be `Array<Item>`.